# get mapWith static domain field value from GrailsDomainClass grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I get mapWith property of a domain class?

I tried domainClass.mapWith as it's a static property of domain class.It didn't work.
I also tried mappedBy but it's a different context.

Any idea on how can i get mapWith value from GrailsDomainClass

Below is my domain:-

```
public class Ticket {
    String id

    List<Long> productInstanceId

    static hasMany = [productInstanceId:Long]

    static mapWith = "none"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a direct check on a particular domain then you can fetch the static property with domain class. In your case it would be `Ticket.mapWith` or `Ticket.class.mapWith`.

If you are doing a dynamic check then you can find it with the help of `DefaultGrailsDomainClass`.

```
GrailsDomainClass aClass = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(clazz)
aClass.mappingStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `GrailsDomainClass` you can access static properties via the Groovy (or Java) class using the `getClazz()` method or its `clazz` property form:

```
GrailsDomainClass dc = ...
String mapWith = dc.clazz.mapWith
```