# What does actually do static mapWith="mongo"?

Tags: mongodb, grails

static mapWith = "mongo"

I am exactly not clear what does it means. According to http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapWith.html

**mapWith**

> **Purpose**
>
> The mapWith static property adds the ability to control if a domain
>   class is being persisted.
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> class Airport {
>   static mapWith = "none"
>
> }
> ```
>
> I also went through this question Remove simpledb mapWith by meta programming in dev mode

and I got an idea that in my grails application,

static mapWith = "mongo"

might be using mongoDB plugin.
But still I am not clear.
I also went through these stackoverflow links :

1. [get mapWith static domain field value from GrailsDomainClass grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625034/get-mapwith-static-domain-field-value-from-grailsdomainclass-grails)
2. [Is it possible in grails to disable persistence of a domain class dynamically with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411469/is-it-possible-in-grails-to-disable-persistence-of-a-domain-class-dynamically-wi)
3. [Migration from MongoDB to PostgreSQL Groovy Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743034/migration-from-mongodb-to-postgresql-groovy-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grails if we want to make certain fields *non-persistent* we can use the **transient** keyword like this:

```
class DomainClass {
static transients = ['field1', 'field2']
Integer field1
Integer field2
Integer persistentField1
Integer persistentField2 
}
```

It is also possible to make a whole domain class *non-persistent* by using **mapwith** keyword.

```
class NonPersistentDomain {
.........
....................
.......................
static mapWith = 'none';
}
```

One can argue that its better to use a command object instead of a domain but it has its own advantages:

It can be accessed using GrailsDomainClass.
It participates while generating UI through scaffolding.

Also see this link

[Grails Data Mapping Mongo Manual](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html/)!

Comment: link is broken as of 2021

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mananpreet Singh's answer, but for the `static mapWith = "mongo"` specifically to be clear is that it means if you want to persist a particular domain class with Mongo not Hibernate, you must use it.

http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#withHibernate